# jquery on submit image not working. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did try every single option, and i'm tired of searching. I hope you could help me on this.

The code below:

```
 <?= FORM::button('submit', __('SUBMIT YOUR AD'), array('type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-publish-new','action'=>Route::url('post_new',array('controller'=>'new','action'=>'index'))))?>
                  </div>
                     </div>
            </fieldset>


<img src="//www.linkinads.com/images/loading-blue.gif" style="display: none;" id="loading">
<script>
$("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function(){

   $(this).show();

 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){

   $(this).hide();

 });
</script>
```

Please let me know any solution please. I'm out of resources. Thank you

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there an error in the console? Or what is the expected behaviour and what your code's doing currently? Please extend your question.

Comment: its not showing the jquery loading image

Comment: after i click submit

Comment: https://codepen.io/DonPramis-dubai/pen/eGpjEM here is the link of the new.php

Comment: try some `console.log` commands to check if ajax are being fired right

Comment: A small tip regarding your set up. I generally prefer toggling a class somewhere in the root element (lets say `ajaxing`). So instead of using `$('#loading').show()` you can use `$('div#main`).addClass('ajaxing')`. You can hide and show your `#loading` using css. This way you can handle your loading gui from html and css in future

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKgXQdAEszU <<< I hope this video will understand what i mean...sorry guys...cany explain much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to all documentations I have seen on jQuery, the `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` events are applied directly to the `$(document)` not to a specific element since these are global events. You can use it like this:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    $("#loading").show();
});
```

Comment: i cant still make it work -- im using this code as advise                      `<img src="//www.linkinads.com/images/loading-blue.gif" style="display: none;" id="loading">
<script>
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    $("#loading").show();
});

 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){

   $(this).hide();

 });
</script> `

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKgXQdAEszU < hi i attached the video link still not working...thank you

Comment: i just tried your code. There were two fixes. 
1. You have have to remove the `;` after the first `}` if you are planing on using the chaining function (that is using the next `.bind(`. 
2. You will need to change the second `$(this)` to `$("#loading")` as well
I have used your code with these modifications here and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/f9mfmppo/

Comment: i did try but not working... i think because of this..`onClick="$.ajax({url : 'https://www.google.com/'})"` how can i replicate this to my code please `<?= FORM::button('submit', __('SUBMIT YOUR AD'), array('type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-publish-new','action'=>Route::url('post_new',array('controller'=>'new','action'=>'index'))))?> `

Comment: I solve the issued by removing the `ajax=>false` from my form code... are they fine.. What you think

Answer (score 0):

Though I dont know the real explanation but removing the

`'data-ajax'=>'false'`

solve my issue.

I hope you can explain to me guys about this solution.. i hope this is okay.

Thanks

Comment: if you removed this from jquery mobile form, data-ajax is designed to load and submit everything via ajax. if you also manually tried any ajax functionality, it is going to interpret with the built in. I used to face a lot of issues with jquery mobile until i set data-ajax to false as well

Comment: its just really weird... but removing it is fixing the issue...i just dont really understand..

Comment: yep i found it weird too. Basically jquery mobile's default ajax will mess around with any custom ajax feature you need